# Why running specific spider doesn't work (but run all the spider)

Tags: scrapy

I created a scrapy project, and want to have two separate spiders (with two different names): 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE8sl.png)

I'm trying to only run "listing_enseigne.py" spider with the command scrapy crawl nameofthespider but it seems that this command also run the other spider (from the file "detail_enseigne.py")...

However when looking in the scrapy documentation,it seems that this command should run only the spider named.

If anyone can help me.. thanks!

Edit 1: 
Indeed, scrapy won't run them both but it will execute all codes in all spiders which run before the actual spider (thanks wishmaster for the answer).
I don't really understand how to organize my spiders then.. 
I want to have a first spider to collect urls from a website (in fact the first spider should export csv files containing multiple information included urls).
Then I want a second spider to find the latest file from the export folder, collecting all urls from this latest file, and then parsing this urls to collect other informations...

Comment: I assume each has a different name, scrapy won't run them both but it will execute all codes in all spiders which run before the actual spider

Comment: above comment is correct. if one spider in your project has errors you can't run any of them.